# Coefficient of $x^r$ in $\frac{1}{(1-ax)^n}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In my combinatorics class, we were taught that the coefficient of $x^r$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$ is $\binom{r+n-1}{r}$. I am struggling to figure out what the coefficient of $x^r$ would be in $\frac{1}{(1-ax)^n}$, where $a \in \mathbb{N}$. I know that the expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$ is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+n-1}{k}x^k$, so my initial thought was that it would be $a^r\binom{r+n-1}{r}$, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put $y = ax$. Then you will have the term $\binom{r + n - 1}{k}y^r = \binom{r + n - 1}{k}(ax)^r = a^r\binom{r + n - 1}{k}x^r$.

Comment: What is $k$ w.r.t. $n$ and $r$?

Comment: Should have said $r$, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: See that coefficient of $x^r$ will be $a^r\binom{r + n - 1}{r}$.